# How to enable cross-origin request in web api 2

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

I know its not a big issue to resolve ,But i am facing problem to consume web api in asp.net MVC web api.

I am getting below error:
"XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://192.168.1.71:800/api/IzoGlass/ToolLocationData. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:58469' is therefore not allowed access".

I've searched and find solution but not working fine with my application.

Description :-When i am consuming web api from same domain in my application its working fine.

but whenever i am consuming webapi from other domain its throwing error. given above.

Answer (score 6):

To enable CORS support, add the Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors NuGet package to your project.

**Controller**

```
[EnableCors(origins: "http://example.com", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    // Controller methods not shown...
}
```

Add `config.EnableCors();` code to:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    // New code
    config.EnableCors();
}
```

**Enable globally**

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    var corsAttr = new EnableCorsAttribute("http://example.com", "*", "*");
    config.EnableCors(corsAttr);
}
```

Reference: http://enable-cors.org/server_aspnet.html

Answer (score 2):

**Enabling Cross-Origin Requests in Web API Layer**

**Step 01 :**
Add the CORS NuGet package. In Visual Studio, from the Tools menu, select Library Package Manager, then select Package Manager Console. In the Package Manager Console window, type the following command:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors
```

**Step 02 :**
Open the file App_Start/WebApiConfig.cs. Add the following code to the WebApiConfig.Register method.

```
using System.Web.Http;
namespace WebService
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // New code
            config.EnableCors();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

**Step 03.**
Next, add the [EnableCors] attribute to the Controller class

```
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Cors;

namespace WebService.Controllers
{
    [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
    public class TestController : ApiController
    {
        // Controller methods not shown...
    }
}
```

Comment: Or in the HttpConfiguration config ; config.EnableCors();

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your WebApiConfig

```
var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
config.EnableCors(cors);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of below policy so you should add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: <origin> | *` into the header of response.

> For security reasons, browsers restrict cross-origin HTTP requests initiated from within scripts.  For example, XMLHttpRequest follows the same-origin policy. So, a web application using XMLHttpRequest could only make HTTP requests to its own domain. To improve web applications, developers asked browser vendors to allow XMLHttpRequest to make cross-domain requests.